# Sencha extjs Tree Panel nodes, autodetect leaf node

Tags: extjs

All the Ext examples I've seen so far with respect to populating and displaying hierarchical data in the tree panel show that you have to have a property named leaf in order to tell if a node is a leaf. Isn't there something that will look at the number of children and detect whether or not the current node is a leaf so I don't have to go traverse my data tree and do it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You have to say "leaf: true" in order to distinguish between a leaf and a folder with no children.  When considering drag and drop, you can put things in folders but not in leafs, so this distinction is important.

Answer (score 0):

As BigSean mentioned you need to write your logic to set a boolean value dynamically such as

checking the nodes length etc.,